# DIV to automatically disappear after 15 seconds unless somebody clicks inside the DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website that will load as as follows:

```
<div class"overlay">
<div id="hideMsg">15 </div>
<div class="mainbox">
</div>
</div>
```

At the moment the overlay disappears after 15 seconds, but i would like to stop this happening if somebody clicks inside the div mainbox. (e.g the box div will no longer disappear. At the same time, I would also like the countdown timer to disappear as it will no longer be needed.

The code I am using is:

**to make the div disappear**

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(1500);
    },15000);
        });
```

**for the countdown timer**

```
var sec = 15
var timer = setInterval(function() {
   $('#hideMsg span').text(sec--);
   if (sec == -1) {
  $('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast');
  clearInterval(timer);
   } 
}, 1000);
```

I think i need to stop the function somehow, but not sure how to do this. Really interested to see what the best way to do this is.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing the timeout `onclick` of `mainbox`.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    var mTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(1500);
    },15000);

    $('.mainbox').click (function () {
       clearTimeout(mTimer);
       $('#hideMsg').fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```